# PowerBI Drill Down from USA State to Counties

Tags: powerbi

I have this Pbix file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/grdscnv974gzqa6/Case8.pbix?dl=0
which shows All countries and their airports with a Drill down to the country feature.

**I am trying to:**

1. Show Only USA map with All States 
2. When you drill down (click on state map it shows all counties).

How to hide all other countries. How to drill down.

This is how my  current map looks like

[image]

This is how the drill-down should look like when you click on the State [image]

Comment: You should use a shape map, that might meet some of your requirements, it will not drill down to sub maps

Comment: @Jonee can I drill down using shape map?

Comment: No, but you can zoom in. See answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to drill down from high level shape map to a lower one using the default shape map or filled map, but you can zoom into selected areas.
You will need to have a hierarchy/table of State to County.

I've used the shape map found [here](https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson/tree/master/countries/united-states/lower-quality-20m), there will be better topoJson files out there with your needs, maybe [this one](https://github.com/topojson/us-atlas).

Also created is a table with an entry for County, and two county names, Clay & Oldham. I've loaded the shape map into the visual. As you can see there are a number of county named the same, this is a limitation of the shape map and data used in this example.

[image]

This gives a map of the USA, and it will zoom into the selected areas. You'll need to change the default auto-zoom setting in the map to allow it to do this

[image]

You'll need to change the default auto-zoom setting in the map to allow it to do this

[image]

Comment: That make sense and will help. Is it possible for you to share the Pbix file?